# Shorter git command for merging development branch into feature branch

Tags: git

To keep my current feature branch in sync with `development` changes I have to do regularly:

```
git checkout development
git pull
git checkout <my feature branch>
git merge development
```

Is it possible to do this `git` commands sequence shorter?

Comment: I would just put that in a script / alias.

Comment: i would recommend rebasing your feature branch rather than merging `git rebase development` on the last line: [more info on rebasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Answer (score 0):

You can always pull directly from the remote upstream branch if you'd like

```
git pull origin development  # Assuming you are on <my feature branch>
```

This will merge in changes from the`development` branch that exists on the remote server (`origin` in this case) that you keep in sync with into `<my feature branch>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git config alias.sync '!git checkout development && git pull && git checkout feature && git merge development'
```

After adding that to your config, you can just do `git sync`.
(The exclamation point at the start tells git to [execute the entire alias as a shell command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias)).

You may also want to add some `git stash` in there before merging the `development` branch.

Comment: Does this alias work only inside current repo or whole host?

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun By default, [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_description) will only apply the alias on the current repo. If you want it to be available on all the repo's on your machine, add the [--global](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---global) option, as in `git config --global alias.*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch origin development:development
git merge development
```